# Элементарное сравнение чисел JS

Tags: javascript

Как на чистом js сравнить цифровое значение элмента

и если оно больше 0 то привоить этому элемнету (или другому элементу) дополнительный класс?

Comment: [Операторы сравнения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого используется обычный оператор сравнение: `if(условие){если да, то выполнить это}else{если нет, то выполнить это};`

```js
function check() {
  var num = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
  if(num > 0){
    document.getElementById('checkbox').classList.add("s1");
    document.getElementById('checkbox').classList.remove("s0");
  }else{
    document.getElementById('checkbox').classList.add("s0");
    document.getElementById('checkbox').classList.remove("s1");
  };
};
```

```css
#checkbox {width:20px;height: 20px;}
#checkbox.s0 {background-color: black}
#checkbox.s1 {background-color: green}
```

```html
<body onload="check()">

<input type="checkbox" onclick="check()">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="check()">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="check()">
  
<div id="checkbox">
</div>
```

Comment: А если значение меняется без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: @Frontendman, при нажатии на кнопку к примеру?

Comment: У меня есть множетсво чекбоксов и скрипт который считает количество отмеченных чекбоксов. И мне нужно подстветить другой элемент (присвоить/удалить класс), если выбран хотя бы один.

Comment: @Frontendman события тебе в помощь

Comment: @Frontendman, смотрите, я изменил ответ. Но если вам нужно удалить или добавить определённый класс, то вот статья: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=2131

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Я немного упростил: создал один класс, который по умолчанию добавлен и по клику удаляется.

Получилось вот так: 
` if(num > 0){
    document.getElementById('checkbox').classList.remove("s1");
  }else{
    document.getElementById('checkbox').classList.add("s1");
  }; `

Comment: @Frontendman, ну то уже по желанию )